# Inside a WPF UserControl, set FontSize on child control to the UserControl's FontSize

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to set the FontSize -- amoung other things -- on some control's within a UserControl to the UserControl-level FontSize. This is not working:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfApplication1.Scratch.UserControlFontSizeProp"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
   <Grid>
       <TextBlock 
        FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},Path=FontSize}">
           Text
       </TextBlock>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: FontSize property is inherited from parent element in the Visual Tree. There's no need to set that. Also, `RelativeSource Self` point's to the `TextBlock`, not the `UserControl`

Comment: Ah, I see my issue now. I was picking up one of my global styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think this should work..

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}" />
```

Comment: This overrides my global style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
FontSize="{Binding Parent.Parent.FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```